# Matlab image shows only black using [0 1.0] image

Tags: image, matlab

I am trying to figure out why my black and white image, with values from 0-1.0 won't be scaled correctly by an image(my_img) call.

I have tried the following:

- Setting colormap([0:0.0039:1; 0:0.0039:1; 0:0.0039:1]')
- Setting clim for the gca to [0 1]
- Setting DataAspectRatio to [1 1 1]
- Changing ClimMode and DataAspectRatioMode to manual

What am I doing wrong?  Matlab documentation states that images can be from [0 1.0]... Why won't image() display it correctly?

Imshow works great BUT I am trying to achieve the same image as imshow for my own personal reasons using the image function.

Constantin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h=image(rand(250, 250));
set(h, 'CDataMapping', 'scaled');
```

`imagesc()` does this automatically, and in fact it was the source code of `imagesc` that gave me the correct property name to use.

Comment: I was sitting there comparing get(gca) using figure(1) and figure(2) did not see that property!

Comment: Right!  That's because it's a property on the image itself, not on the axis.

Comment: Yep, I meant to imply the "DOH" with my comment.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`image` documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/image.html) (see the table under the heading "Tips") you can either call `image` with an array of RGB values or an indexed colourmap, the later seems to be what you are doing. From this same table it states that an indexed colourmap:

> is stored as a two-dimensional (m-by-n) array of integers in the range `[1, length(colormap)];` colormap is an m-by-3 array of floating-point values in the range [0, 1].

The key point here is that the values in your image array, `my_img`, should be in the range `1` to `256` (I have guessed this from the line "Setting `colormap([0:0.0039:1; 0:0.0039:1; 0:0.0039:1]'`", you may need to change this). However, you have values in the range 0 to 1, which are all being mapped to the first colour in you colourmap, which I presume is `(0, 0, 0)` or black.

Comment: Hi chris, I appreciate your response, and it makes sense... you're saying I'm indexing the colormap instead of scaling to it?

Comment: Spot on! This is what is meant by `indexed (colormap)` in the MATLAB documentation.